# Refresh Page Without Re-Rendering DOM

Tags: php, jquery, caching, metadata

This might sound like it's an easy question to answer but please read when my full question is before answering with `<?php echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=./live'>"; ?>` or `<?php header ('Location: ./'); ?>`.

I am having issues with a little project of mine. As usual I've searched stackoverflow and Google extensively for a while to this solution, but as of yet cannot find one.

**My Question:**

Is it possible to have a page refresh itself without re-rendering the DOM (by re-rendering the DOM, I mean not having the page go white and re load all of the page contents).

**What I've Looked Into:**

```
<?php
    $time = time();
    $event_time = '1371772800';

    if($time > $event_time) {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=./'>";
        exit();
    }
?>
```

This works great, however it doesn't detect if the `$event_time` value has been met until the user reloads the page manually, so I added `<meta http-equiv=Refresh content='10; URL=./'>` into my HMTL which also works great. *However* the browser still re-renders the entire DOM, displaying that distracting white flash (if only for a few seconds).

**To sum up:**

- Is there a way to achieve this in PHP or JQuery?
- Is there a way to force Cache the page for a set time so the browser doesn't re-render?

As usual, any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

I have looked into AJAX solutions and have not found any, as I am not looking to update any objects on the page. I am looking for the page to redirect when the $event_time variable is met. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: Any time you reload the page, it will blink out and back on. The browser doesn't know it is the same page. It sees it as a new document. What you want is AJAX. You want to load only the changed content (in JavaScript/AJAX) and then update the changed object in the page. It may not come out seamless as the changed content may force the page to resize a bit, but it won't completely blank out.

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to use AJAX.

Comment: Can we ask you what are you looking to achieve with this behavior? Why do you want to do it?

Comment: @kainaw, I have looked into AJAX solutions and have not found any, as I am not looking to update any objects on the page. I am looking for the page to redirect when the $event_time variable is met. Is there a way to do this in PHP?

Comment: @Enijar your question still not clear for me. I didn't have my answers...

Comment: @Steve I'm not sure if this is possible, which is why it's so hard for me to ask, but I'll try again. Is it possible to redirect the page, without the user reloading the page and for the PHP to redirect the user from the page they are viewing once the variable `$event_time` has been met?

Comment: @Enijar As people has already said, you need to use Ajax. It is totally possible but you have to deal with the time on the client side  passing the data through PHP or creating it there.

Comment: You have to use Ajax to update your different time variables so that php can know when the condition is met.

Comment: @Steve Okay, great any pointers as to where I can get an example of AJAX checking if the PHP variable has been met, or will this all have to be done in JavaScript?

Comment: @Enijar you need to read more about AJAX.

Comment: How can AJAX check a PHP variable? Easy. AJAX is used to load something like check_variable.php, which is a page that prints 1 if the variable is set or 0 if not (or whatever makes sense). Then, based on what the page prints, which is the value AJAX receives, the JavaScript does something.

Comment: @kainaw Thanks, already got it now.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020, You can use [`turbolinks.js`](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) or [`pjax`](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax) to do like single page application.